# Passing nested knockout view model to controller

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

This is fleet management app in mvc EF and knockout , there are VEHICLES , DRIVERS and specific ROUTES that the drivers travel.

I have a situation where I would like to gather field values from three models nested within my view models into a single object and post it my backend via ajax. I want this to be triggered by clicking a button.

There is a problem is in my `populateFleetInformation` function. When I gather the field values from my various models, some of the observables are losing their values and appear as null.

**The view model that attempts to make the ajax call**

```
    function FleetViewModel() {
    var vvm = this;
    vvm.regNumber = ko.observable(0);
    vvm.make = ko.observable("");
    vvm.model = ko.observable("");
    vvm.RouteDetail = new RouteViewModel();
    vvm.SaveFleetInfo = function(item){
        if (!pageViewModel.isAuthenticated()) return;
        populateFleetInformation(item);
        $.when(postSecureData("/api/Fleet/", ko.toJSON(pageViewModel.FleetViewModel.RouteViewModel.RouteDriverViewModel)))
          .done(function () {   
              document.getElementById("save-Fleet-btn").innerHTML = "Saving...";
              setTimeout(function () { document.getElementById("save-fleet-btn").innerHTML = "Save" }, 2500);
              $.msgGrowl({
                  type: 'info',
                  title: 'Fleet Information',
                  text: 'fleet information succesfully saved',
                  position: 'bottom-right',
                  lifetime: 3000
              });

          })

    }

}
```

**function that gathers data**

```
function PopulateFleetInformation(item)
{
    pageViewModel.fleetVM.regNumber(item.regNumber);
    pageViewModel.fleetVM.make(item.make);
    pageViewModel.fleetVM.model.(item.model);
    pageViewModel.fleetVM.routeDetail.routeID(item.routeId);
    pageViewModel.fleetVM.routeDetail.routeName(item.routeName);
    pageViewModel.fleetVM.routeDriver.nationalId(item.nationalId);
    pageViewModel.fleetVM.individualMsisdn.licenseId(item.licenseId);
    pageViewModel.fleetVM.individualMsisdn.driverName(item.driverName);

}
```

**The trigger button**

```
 <button type="submit" id="save-fleet-btn" class="btn"data-bind="click: $root.fleetVM.sensorDetail.SaveFleetInfo"></button>
```

Comment: Where are you expecting `item` in `PopulateFleetInformation` to come from, the UI or from the result of ajax call?

Comment: @Anish Patel from the UI and then I want to pass those values(item ) to controller , that is why the populate method is before the post method

Comment: Where is the ajax call,  is it `postSecureData`? What does the ajax call return?

Comment: yes its post secure data , so user enters all that info in matching my knockout and clicks on save

Comment: Ah okay, so you post `RouteDriverViewModel` to your web api controller and the controller returns an object with `regNumer`, `make`, `model`, etc?

Comment: yes I must post regNumer, make, model, etc?  to controller , then the controller points to the repository which will then save the info in the sql database

Comment: Now you've lost me. Can please post the code of your controller and `RouteDriverViewModel`.

Answer (score 1):

This function:

```
function PopulateFleetInformation(item)
{
    pageViewModel.fleetVM.regNumber(item.regNumber);
    pageViewModel.fleetVM.make(item.make);
    pageViewModel.fleetVM.model.(item.model);
    pageViewModel.fleetVM.routeDetail.routeID(item.routeId);
    pageViewModel.fleetVM.routeDetail.routeName(item.routeName);
    pageViewModel.fleetVM.routeDriver.nationalId(item.nationalId);
    pageViewModel.fleetVM.individualMsisdn.licenseId(item.licenseId);
    pageViewModel.fleetVM.individualMsisdn.driverName(item.driverName);

}
```

is **not** doing what you think it is at all.

`item`is coming from the context passed into `SaveFleetInfo` by knockout when your button is clicked. This function is then setting the values of the fields you are trying to retrieve to whatever is in `item`; I'm guessing you're getting all sorts of `undefined` exceptions here.

**What you want to do is this:**

```
function PopulateFleetInformation() 
{ 
   return { 
      regNumber: pageViewModel.fleetVM.regNumber(); 
      make: pageViewModel.fleetVM.make(); 
      model: pageViewModel.fleetVM.model.(); 
      routeId: pageViewModel.fleetVM.routeDetail.routeID(); 
      routeName: pageViewModel.fleetVM.routeDetail.routeName(); 
      nationalId: pageViewModel.fleetVM.routeDriver.nationalId(); 
      licenseId: pageViewModel.fleetVM.individualMsisdn.licenseId(); 
      driverName: pageViewModel.fleetVM.individualMsisdn.driverName(); 
    } 
}
```

This function returns the values you are after as an object, then you can post this data like this:

```
    var data = populateFleetInformation();
    $.when(postSecureData("/api/Fleet/", ko.toJSON(data)))
```